# What is the best way to compare if two binaries (C++) are equivalent in Linux while ignoring metadata?

Tags: c++, linux, binary, diff, patch

I am trying to check which binaries differ in a directory in order to create a patch replacing the old binary. I have access to the source code and the repository (GIT). When I compare the two binaries generated from the exact same source code using `diff` or `cmp` the binaries are reported to be different. I assume this is due to metadata or other data that is compiled into the code but is irrelevant to how the binaries behave.

Ideally, I would like to compare the binaries while ignoring any "extra" data. If this is not possible then I would like to compile the binaries while stripping any "extra" data so that the same source code generates the same exact binaries. A lot of the binaries have cross dependencies where one binary is used by another binary and so if one binary changes the other one must be replaced as well.

I am trying to generate a patch that replaces old binaries with new ones and any other binaries that need to replaced as a result of the changes in the new binary.

Comment: Why do you assume the difference to be *due to metadata or other data that is compiled into the code but is irrelevant to how the binaries behave*?

Comment: Compiler version X will very likely produce a different binary from compiler version Y. The visible behaviour should be the same (excepting [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)), but the method used to produce the behaviour could be radically different.

Comment: If the binaries are created by you, one idea is to hash the source code and inject it into the binary. Comparison would be done by extracting the hash and comparing it.

Comment: @eerorika, both binaries are compiled from the same source, using the same compiler, configuration, environment, etc. But there are differences in the binaries. That's why I assumed some metadata, ex. timestamps, were inserted into the binaries.

Comment: @jdigital, thank you for the suggestion. How would you go about injecting the code and extracting the code from the binary?

Comment: @jdigital. Furthermore, would this method cover cases where the changes in the source code of binary A also results in changes to binary B because binary A is dependency of binary B? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @GoldySingh You should add the new details to the question. Another question: Do any of the sources use macros such as `__TIME__`. Those can change the meaning of the source across different compilations.

Comment: This is a good question. My problem is similar, only I am trying to cross-compile on a different platform requiring some updates to a very complex Makefile ruleset,and I want to isolate where the differences are so I can see if the cause is trivial metadata or important #defines not being set.